# Can I view a Plutus smart contract on the NFT marketplace?

Tags: smart-contract

Can I view a Plutus smart contract of an NFT from the marketplace like (JPG store) and what is PubKeyHash ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot view it directly on the chain.

The `PubKeyHash` is just the payment part of their contract address.

It is a good custom that the smart contract should be open source, in the case of jpg.store, their contract is [released on github as contract-v2](https://github.com/jpg-store/contract-v2).